# How to find out the cause of EC2 EBS I/O requests?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I have a EC2 instant. The Account Activity is showed below.
[image]

My EBS I/O requests is very large. I run socket.io with Node.js which has about 1,000 users connecting the socket. But the traffic of the socket is very small. About a data transport(a string) per 10 minutes. So, is there a way to find out the cause? Thanks.

Comment: Check your memory usage, is your instance pushing to swap? That is something that can be quite common on a micro instance. Otherwise look at your application to see if its reading/writing to disk. Log files included.

Comment: I have used no swap. Please see this image which run top command http://i.imgur.com/8YcPcpf.png

Comment: Try disabling log files generated by Apache and see if that reduces your IO usage. You could also try a lighter weight webserver like nginx. Its possible mysql might be hitting the disk more often due to memory constraints as well.